# Is it possible to dynamically set data_class in configureOptions?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, inheritance, symfony-forms

I'm trying to refactor some bad code, currently I have over 20 forms (dictionaries) with a single field called `name` and two similar forms (dictionaries) with extra fields.

These forms are being embedded as a collection in another form, where `entry_type` is dynamically set to one of the former forms, based on value returned from my factory.

The purpose was to modify selects during edition of some other forms, so the user could freely add or remove options with new button/delete buttons.

I've tried to remove my 20 forms by creating a base form with a single field - `name` and configuring `data_class` in `configureOptions` dynamically but I couldn't find a way to do that. When I've tried to modify a constructor and set the value there, I couldn't access the constructor during `createForm` - I can only pass options, but options aren't accessible in `configureOptions`.

I was able to find that it was possible in older version of symfony via `$this->createForm(new FormType($option))`

Is it possible to do a similar thing in symfony 5? If not, what are the workarounds?

If I can improve the question anyhow, please let me know. Here is the code:

Action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/dictionary/getForm/{id}",
 *     name="dictionary_form")
 * @param $id
 */    
public function getDictionaryView(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, $id){

    $repository = $em->getRepository('App:'.substr($id, 3));
    $items = $repository->findAll();
    
    $form = $this->createForm(DictionaryCollectionType::class,['dictionary' => $items],array(
        'type' => DictionaryFormFactory::createForm($id),
        'action' => $id,
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        $data = $form->getData()['dictionary'];
        $idsForm = array_map(function($item) {return $item->getId();},$data);
        foreach($items as $item) {
            if(!in_array($item->getId(),$idsForm)) $em->remove($item);
        }

        foreach($data as $entity) {
            $em->persist($entity);
        }

        $em->flush();

        $return = [];
        foreach($data as $entity) {
            $append = ['value' => $entity->getId(), 'name' => $entity->getName()];
            if($entity instanceof DegreesDisciplines) $append['field'] = $entity->getField()->getId();
            $return[] = $append;
        }

        return new JsonResponse($return);

    }

    return $this->render('Admin\Contents\dictionary.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

(Idea of) Base form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Dictionaries;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class NewDictionaryType extends AbstractType {

    private $data_class;

    public function __construct($data_class)
    {
        $this->data_class = $data_class;
    }
    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Nazwa',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => $this->data_class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Example form that repeats. Basically, only 'data_class' changes in other forms:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Dictionaries;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class NewNoticesTypeType extends AbstractType {
    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Nazwa',
            'required' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\NoticesTypes',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Parent form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class DictionaryCollectionType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('dictionary', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => $options['type'],
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
            'empty_data' => null,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'label' => false,
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'save btn btn-success mt-2', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#dictionaryBackdrop', 'action' => $options['action']],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'type' => null,
            'action' => null
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for info, starting in 2.8 the form system took over the creation of formtypes.  Only one instance of a given type is ever actually instantiated.  Hopefully you can get the options approach discussed in the answer to work.  Otherwise, well at least you know why your predecessor made 20 almost identical forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a constructor to pass configuration options, but just use `createForm` to pass options:

```
$form = $this->createForm(DictionaryCollectionType::class,['dictionary' => $items],array(
    'type' => DictionaryFormFactory::createForm($id),
    'action' => $id,
    'data_class' => $dataClass // <-- put your data class (FQCN) here
));
```

See Symfony's documentation about [Passing Options to Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#passing-options-to-forms)

One more thing you probably should refactor is `'App:'.substr($id, 3)`. It's better to use a FQCN instead of the old `Bundle:Entity` format.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! I'll try to look into FQCN, but in the meantime - If I pass `$dataClass` as options, how do I set `data_class` to  the necessary value in `configureOptions` part? (It's what I'm trying to achieve in base form). If I'm somehow unclear, do let me know.

Comment: In your `configureOptions` method, you're setting the *default* values of your form. By `'data_class' => $dataClass` from my answer, you're overriding this default value. So setting the `data_class` in your controller with override the `null` from the defaults.

Comment: Thanks! It made it clearer and I've got it to work. Just to make the answer full, in case anyone needs it in future, I only had to move `data_class` to `entry_options`, so the code in my parent form (`DictionaryCollectionType`) is as follows: `'entry_options' => array('label' => false, 'data_class' => DictionaryFormFactory::getDataClass($options['action'])),`